# Turn off (suppress) Msg 3013 "BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally"

Tags: sql-server, backup

When backup operation fails, it produces 2 error msgs

```
Msg 911, Level 16, State 11, Line 22
Database 'not_existing_db' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

It is making it very hard to capture the "root cause" error message (example 911) instead of that generic 3013 message

Is there any way to suppress message 3013 so SQL Server does not throw it anymore ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to suppress message 3013 so SQL Server does not throw it anymore ?

I would say do not suppress, but have your scripts intelligent enough to not generate false/ unnecessary alerts.

What can be done ?

Before taking backup, put some validation

e.g. check if database exists in sys.database, is online and accessible (not secondary or offline), etc and then kick off your backup.

[Ola's backup solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) is quiet intelligent in those terms.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to "suppress" the error, nor would I *personally* want to. The error is letting you know **something** happened and it's up to you to go figure out what that something was.

In your example, it says the database doesn't exist. Let's say you lost connectivity to disks, or there was corruption, or ... ad nausea. In this way, you can key off of the 3013 error as a general "backup database issue" (alert) and then investigate further.

Assuming you could suppress the error message, you'd either have to have an alert or line item for each individual error that *could possibly happen* or just go about your day until someone or something complains. Either way, not so good.